# pasar variable url a json

Tags: php, mysql

buen dia soy nuevo en php y tengo un codigo de calendario creado en php y mysql lo que quiero es hacer que el calendario en la consulta aparte de filtrar por fechas filtre por un usuario que es enviado por una variable url adjunto el codigo. cuando pongo la variable $_GET['ejemplo'] en la consulta no me muestra nada, si pongo el texto manual si me filtra

```js
<?php
 class calendar extends calendarExtensions
 {
  ###############################################################################################
  #### Properties
  ###############################################################################################
  
  // Initializes A Container Array For All Of The Calendar Events
  var $json_array = array();
  var $categories = '';
  var $connection = '';
  var $filter ='';
  var $uploadDir = '';
  ############################################################################################### 
  #### Methods
  ###############################################################################################
  
  /**
  * Construct
  * Returns connection
  */
  public function __construct($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $table, $condition=false, $cf='')
  {
   // Set Internal Variables
   $this->db_server = $db_server; 
   $this->db_username = $db_username;
   $this->db_password = $db_password;
   $this->db_name = $db_name;
   $this->table = $table; 
   
   $this->filter = $cf;
   $this->condition = $condition;
   
   // Connection @params 'Server', 'Username', 'Password'
   $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->db_server, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);
   
   // Display Friend Error Message On Connection Failure
   if(!$this->connection) 
   {
    header('Location: _install.php');
    exit();
    //die('Could not connect: ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') - ' . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   
   // Internal UTF-8
   mysqli_query($this->connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
   mysqli_query($this->connection, 'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
   mysqli_query($this->connection, 'SET character_set_client=utf8');
   mysqli_query($this->connection, 'SET character_set_results=utf8');
   

   // json_transform filter
   $start = @$this->filter['start'];
   $end = @$this->filter['end'];
   $doctor = @$this->$doctor1;
   
   if(isset($start) && isset($end))
   {
    $newdate_start = strtotime('-4 months', strtotime($start));
    $start = date('Y-m-d', $newdate_start);
    
    $newdate_end = strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($end));
    $end = date('Y-m-d', $newdate_end);
   }
   
   //  ############################################################################################### 
  #### AQUI ESTA EL DETALLE DONDE NECESITO MOSTRAR LA VARIABLE
  ############################################################################################### ////
   $dc = '';
   if($this->condition == false)
   {
    if(strlen($start) !== 0 && strlen($end) !== 0) 
    {
     $dc = sprintf(" WHERE start >= '%s' AND end <= '%s' AND doctor = 'aqui la variable'", addslashes($start), addslashes($end), addslashes($doctor));
    }

    $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->table $dc");
   } else {
    
    if(strlen($start) !== 0 && strlen($end) !== 0) 
    {
     $dc = sprintf(" AND start >= '%s' AND end <= '%s' AND doctor = ' aqui la variable'", addslashes($start), addslashes($end), addslashes($doctor));
    } 
    $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE $this->condition $dc"); 
   }
   
  }
  
  /**
  * Function To Transform MySQL Results To jQuery Calendar Json
  * Returns converted json
  */
  public function json_transform()
  {
   while($this->row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {
     if($this->row['allDay'] == 'true') 
     {
      $allDayStatus = true;
     } else {
     $allDayStatus = false;  
     }
     
     // Set Variables Data from DB
     $event_id = $this->row['repeat_id'];
     $event_original_id = $this->row['id'];
     $event_title = $this->row['title'];
     $event_description = $this->row['description'];
     $event_start = $this->row['start'];
     $event_end = $this->row['end'];
     $event_allDay = $allDayStatus;
     $event_color = $this->row['color'];
     $event_url = $this->row['url'];

     $build_json = array('id' => $event_id, 'original_id' => $event_original_id, 'title' => $event_title, 'start' => $event_start, 'end' => $event_end, 'allDay' => $event_allDay, 'color' => $event_color);
     
     array_push($this->json_array, $build_json);  
        
   } // end while loop
   
   // Output The Json Formatted Data So That The jQuery Call Can Read It
   return json_encode($this->json_array); 
  }
  
  /**
  * This function will check for repetitive events (since 1.6.4)
  * Returns true
  */
  public function check_repetitive_events($id)
  {
   $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE repeat_id != id AND id = %d || repeat_id = %d',
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $id),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $id)
   );
   
   $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
   
   if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 1)
   {
    return true; 
   } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    if($row['id'] == $row['repeat_id'])
    {
     return false;
    } else {
     return true; 
    }
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
  }
  
  /**
  * This function will update event on drag or resize
  * Returns boolean
  */
  public function update($allDay, $start, $end, $id, $original_id)
  {   
   // Convert Date Time
   $start = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime(substr($start, 0, 24)));
   $end = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime(substr($end, 0, 24)));
   
   $allDay_value = $allDay;
   
   // Before updating on drag or resize check if it is repetitive event
   $is_rep = $this->check_repetitive_events($original_id);

   if($is_rep == true)
   {
    $process = $this->repetitive_event_procedure($allDay, $start, $end, $id, $original_id, '');
    
    if($process == true)
    {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false; 
    }
    }
   
   // The update query for normal events
   $query = sprintf('UPDATE %s 
         SET 
          start = "%s",
          end = "%s",
          allDay = "%s"
         WHERE
          repeat_id = %s
      ',
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $start),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $end),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $allDay_value),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $id)
      );
   
   // The result
   return $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
  }
  
  /**
  * This function updates events to the database (Edit Update)
  * Returns true
  */
  public function updates($post, $file, $id_field = '')
  { 
   // Handle Upload
   $post = $this->handle_file_upload($post, $file);
   
   if(strlen($id_field) == '') 
   { 
    $start = $post['start_date'].' '.$post['start_time'].':00';
    $end = $post['end_date'].' '.$post['end_time'].':00';
   } else { 
    $start = $post['start'];
    $end = $post['end'];
    $id_field = 'id';
   }
   
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $post['id']);
   
   if(isset($post['rep_id']) && strlen($post['rep_id']) !== 0)
   {
    $is_rep = $this->check_repetitive_events($id);
    
    if($is_rep == true)
    { 
     $process = $this->repetitive_event_procedure($post['allDay'], $start, $end, $post['rep_id'], $id, $post);
     
     if($process == true)
     {
      return true;
     } else {
      return false; 
     }
     }
   }
   
   if(strlen($id_field) == '')
   {
    $id_field = 'id';
   }
   
   // The update query
   $query = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET 
          title = '%s',
          description = '%s',
          color = '%s',
          start = '%s',
          end = '%s',
          url = '%s',
          category = '%s',
          allDay = '%s'
         WHERE
         {$id_field} = %d
      ",
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, strip_tags($post['title'])),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['description'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['color'])),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $start),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $end),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['url'])),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['categorie'])),
          mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $post['allDay']),
          $id
          
      );
   
   $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
   
   unset($post['rep_id'], $post['method'], $post['id'], $post['end_date'], $post['end_time'], $post['start_date'], $post['start_time'], $post['allDay'], $post['repeat_times'], $post['repeat_method'], $post['categorie']);
   
   // add all other custom fields
   $this->update_custom_fields($post, $id);
  }
  
  /**
  * This function adds events to the database
  * Returns true
  */
  public function addEvent($post, $file='')
  { 
   // Avoid empty title
   if(strlen($post['title']) == 0)
   {
    return false;
   }
   
   // Avoid empty start date
   if(strlen($post['start_date']) == 0)
   {
    return false;
   }
   
   // Check for empty data
   if(empty($post['title']) && empty($post['start_date']))
   {
    return false; 
   }
   
   // Checking URL
   if(empty($post['url'])) 
   {
    $post['url'] = 'false';
   }
   
   // Handle Upload
   $post = $this->handle_file_upload($post, $file);
   
   // Convert Date Time
   $start = $post['start_date'].' '.$post['start_time'].':00';
   $end = $post['end_date'].' '.$post['end_time'].':00';
   
   // Prepare Existing Fields
   $post['title'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, strip_tags($post['title']));
   $post['description'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['description'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
   $post['start_date'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['start_date']));
   $post['start_time'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['start_time']));
   $post['end_date'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['end_date']));
   $post['end_time'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['end_time']));
   $post['all-day'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $post['all-day']);
   $post['color'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['color']));
   $post['url'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['url']));
   $post['categorie'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['categorie'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
   $post['user_id'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['user_id']));
   $post['repeat_method'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['repeat_method']));
   $post['repeat_times'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, htmlspecialchars($post['repeat_times']));
   
   // Copy
   $fields = $post;
   
   // Insert Default Data
   if(isset($post) && is_array($post))
   { 
    $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s 
          SET 
           title = "%s",
           description = "%s",
           start = "%s",
           end = "%s",
           allDay = "%s",
           color = "%s",
           url = "%s",
           category = "%s",
           user_id = %d,
           repeat_type = "%s",
           repeat_id = "%s"
       ',
           mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table),
           $post['title'],
           $post['description'],
           $start,
           $end,
           $post['all-day'],
           $post['color'],
           $post['url'],
           $post['categorie'],
           $post['user_id'],
           $post['repeat_method'],
           "0"
       );
       
    unset($post['title'], $post['description']);
    unset($post['start_date'], $post['start_time'], $post['end_date'], $post['end_time']);
    unset($post['all-day'], $post['color'], $post['url'], $post['categorie']);
    unset($post['user_id']);
    unset($post['repeat_method'], $post['repeat_times']);
    
    // The result
    $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
    $inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
   } 
   
   // Handle Custom Fields and Other Data
   if($this->result) 
   {
    // update repeat_id
    mysqli_query(
     $this->connection, 
     sprintf("UPDATE %s SET repeat_id = %d WHERE id = %d", mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table), $inserted_id, $inserted_id)
    );
    
    // add all other custom fields
    $this->update_custom_fields($post, $inserted_id);
    
    // deal with repetitive events
    if(strlen($inserted_id) !== 0)
    { 
     if($fields['repeat_method'] == 'no')
     {
      return true;
     } else {
      $current_date = date('d', strtotime($fields['start_date']));
      $current_month = date('m', strtotime($fields['start_date']));
      $current_year = date('Y', strtotime($fields['start_date']));
      
      $fields['table'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table);
      $fields['repeat_id'] = $inserted_id;
      
      $added_repetitive_events = $this->insert_repetitive_events($fields, $current_date, $current_month, $current_year); 
      
      if($added_repetitive_events)
      {
       return true; 
      }
     }
    } else {
     return false; 
    }
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
  }
  
  /**
  * This function deletes event from database
  * Returns true
  */
  public function delete($id, $rep_id, $method='')
  {
   // Delete Query
   if($method == '')
   {
    $query = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id = $id";  
   } else {
    $query = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE repeat_id = $rep_id";  
   }
   
   // Result
   $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
   
   if($this->result) 
   {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
   
  }
  
  /**
  * This function will get description (since 1.6.4)
  * Returns true
  */
  public function get_description($id)
  {
   $query = sprintf('SELECT description FROM %s WHERE id = %d',
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $id)
   );
   
   $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($res) >= 1)
   {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $result['description'];
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
  }
  
  /**
  * This function will get event data (since 2.0)
  * Returns boolean
  */
  public function get_event($id)
  {
   $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = %d',
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $this->table),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $id)
   );
   
   $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($res) >= 1)
   {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $result;
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
  }
  
  /**
  * This function retrieves calendar data
  * Returns true
  */
  public function retrieve($id)
  {
   // Result Query
   $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, sprintf("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id = %s", mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $id)));
   
   if($this->result) {
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->result);
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
    
  }
  
  /**
  * Gets all Categories - since version 1.4
  * Returns array
  */
  public function getCategories()
  {
   // Set default category in case the user do not have categories with events
   $results = $this->categories;
   asort($results);
   $return = array_unique(array_filter($results));
   
   if(count($return) == 0)
   {
    return false;
   } else {
    return $return; 
   }
  }
  
  /**
  * This function exports each event to the icalendar format and forces a download
  * Returns true
  */  
  public function icalExport($id, $title, $description, $start_date, $end_date, $url=false)
  {
   
   if($url == 'undefined') 
   {
    $url = '';
   } else {
    $url = ' '.$url.' '; 
   }
   
   $event = $this->get_event($id);
   
   $description_fn = $str = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\t"),'\n',$description);
   
   // Build the ics file
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Paulo Regina//Ajax Calendar 2.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:'.date('Ymd\This', time()).'Z'.'
DESCRIPTION:'.$description_fn.'
DTEND:'.$end_date.'
DTSTAMP:'.date('Ymd\This', time()).'Z'.'
DTSTART:'.$start_date.'
CATEGORIES:'.$event['category'].'
AFFC-ALLDAY:'.$event['allDay'].'
AFFC-COLOR:'.$event['color'].'
AFFC-URL:'.$event['url'].'
AFFC-UID:'.$event['user_id'].'
LAST-MODIFIED:'.date('Ymd\This', time()).'Z'.'
SUMMARY:'.addslashes($title).'
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';
    
   if(isset($id)) {
    return $ical;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
  
  /**
  * Export entire calendar to icalendar (since 1.6.4)
  * Returns true
  */
  public function icalExport_all($uid=0)
  {
   
   if(isset($uid))
   {
    $u_f = $uid;
   } else {
    $u_f = 0; 
   }
   
   $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE user_id = $u_f");
   
   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
   {
    $ical = '';
    
$ical .= 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' ."\n";
$ical .= 'PRODID:-//Paulo Regina//Ajax Calendar 2.0 MIMEDIR//EN'."\n";
$ical .= 'VERSION:2.0'."\n";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
$ical .= 'BEGIN:VEVENT'."\n";
$ical .= 'CREATED:'.date('Ymd\This', time()).'Z'."\n";
$ical .= 'DESCRIPTION:'.str_replace(array("\r","\n","\t"),'\n',$row['description'])."\n";
$ical .= 'DTEND:'.date('Ymd\This', strtotime($row['end'])).'Z'."\n";
$ical .= 'DTSTAMP:'.date('Ymd\This', time()).'Z'."\n";
$ical .= 'DTSTART:'.date('Ymd\This', strtotime($row['start'])).'Z'."\n";
$ical .= 'CATEGORIES:'.$row['category']."\n";
$ical .= 'AFFC-ALLDAY:'.$row['allDay']."\n";
$ical .= 'AFFC-COLOR:'.$row['color']."\n";
$ical .= 'AFFC-URL:'.$row['url']."\n";
$ical .= 'AFFC-UID:'.$row['user_id']."\n";
$ical .= 'LAST-MODIFIED:'.date('Ymd\This', time()).'Z'."\n";
$ical .= 'SUMMARY:'.addslashes($row['title'])."\n";
$ical .= 'END:VEVENT'."\n";   
    }
$ical .= 'END:VCALENDAR'."\n";

   return $ical;
   
   } else {
    return false; 
   }
    
  }
   
 }

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Cuando se trata de programas enteros, conviene que indiques en qué parte del código se encuentra el problema. Aquí tú has puesto varios cientos de líneas de código, las cuales habría que analizar para luego tratar de adivinar dónde se encuentra el problema. Por ejemplo, **¿en qué parte envías el dato que quieres recuperar luego por `GET`? ¿en qué parte recuperas luego ese dato?** Creo que son solamente esas las partes del código que debiste haber mostrado.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano si indico donde esta el problema como comentario, la variable la paso en un url por ejemplo http:mipagina.com/?variable=doc1 y quiero que se muestre en la consulta dnde dice en el comentario aqui el problema hay un where que dice docto= 'aqui necesito mostrarlo'
 gracias amigo